# "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'" ошибка

Tags: c#, postgresql

Я использую PostgreSQL

```
 "metadata=res://AstralInvoiceRevise.DataService/DataModel.InvoiceRevise.csdl|res://AstralInvoiceRevise.DataService/DataModel.InvoiceRevise.ssdl|res://AstralInvoiceRevise.DataService/DataModel.InvoiceRevise.msl;provider=Devart.Data.PostgreSql;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=vasya;Password=123;Host=127.0.0.1;Database=invoice_revise;Character Set=WIN1251;Initial Schema=public&quot;"

WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("InvoiceReviseEntitiesConnectionString", "ro_users", "user_id", "login", false);
```

при инициализации выходит ошибка "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'"

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Эта строчка является строкой соединения для Entity Framework'а, но не является строкой соединения с БД. `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` же ожидает строчку соединения с БД, которая содержится внутри, в параметре `provider connection string`.

Попробуйте вытащить ее с помощью [`EntityConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.providerconnectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), через свойство [`ProviderConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.providerconnectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), и затем передать в вызов `InitializeDatabaseConnection`.